# plt.plot(...) doesn't show a window. what am I missing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am practicing with open cv on VScode.

I am used to display images by using the following structure:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

puppy = cv2.imread('./DATA/00-puppy.jpg')
horse = cv2.imread('./DATA/horse.jpg')
rainbow = cv2.imread('./DATA/rainbow.jpg')

# "inplace" operations on these images such as
# puppy = cv2.cvtColor(puppy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# etc...

img_to_show_1 = puppy
img_to_show_2 = horse
img_to_show_3 = rainbow

# ---> beginning of the "while True ... - if 0xFF == 27: break" structure

cv2.namedWindow(winname='window_1')
cv2.namedWindow(winname='window_2')
cv2.namedWindow(winname='window_3')


while True:
    cv2.imshow('window_1', img_to_show_1)
    cv2.imshow('window_2', img_to_show_2)    
    cv2.imshow('window_3', img_to_show_3)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27: # stop loop when 'esc' key is pressed
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# ---> end of the "while True ... - if 0xFF == 27: break" structure
```

Now I have calculated the histogram of the values of an image stored in `puppy` variable

```
hist_values = cv2.calcHist([puppy], channels=[0], mask=None, histSize=[256], ranges=[0,256])
```

On jupyter notebooks, this can be showed by simply doing:

```
plt.plot(hist_values)
```

But on VScode, this does not show anything.

Is there a way to show this image on VScode and without intalling any other graphical extention?

Is there a way to exploit the same "while True ... - if 0xFF == 27: break" structure, in order to have this image also disappear with the others as I press 'esc' key?

Comment: GUIs can't be mixed. do not mix matplotlib and opencv's imshow(). learn about matplotlib. you are missing the `plt.show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to do it.

This is based on saving the image with opencv module method and to reload it with the matplotlib method:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

puppy = cv2.imread('./DATA/00-puppy.jpg')
horse = cv2.imread('./DATA/horse.jpg')
rainbow = cv2.imread('./DATA/rainbow.jpg')

# "inplace" operations on these images such as
# puppy = cv2.cvtColor(puppy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# etc...

hist_values = cv2.calcHist([puppy], channels=[0], mask=None, histSize=[256], ranges=[0,256])

plt.plot(hist_values)
plt.plot([1, 2])
mypath = 'my/path/hist_values.jpg'
plt.savefig(mypath)

hist_values_img = cv2.imread(mypath)

import os
try: 
    os.remove(hist_values_path)
except: 
    print("could not remove {}".format(hist_values_path))

img_to_show_1 = puppy
img_to_show_2 = hist_values_img
img_to_show_3 = rainbow

# ---> beginning of the "while True ... - if 0xFF == 27: break" structure

cv2.namedWindow(winname='window_1')
cv2.namedWindow(winname='window_2')
cv2.namedWindow(winname='window_3')

while True:
    cv2.imshow('window_1', img_to_show_1)
    cv2.imshow('window_2', img_to_show_2)    
    cv2.imshow('window_3', img_to_show_3)
    plt.show()

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27: # se premo esc
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# ---> end of the "while True ... - if 0xFF == 27: break" structure
```

In this way I am not mixing GUIs and as I press 'esc', the histogram image closes together with the other images.

Credits to @ChristophRackwitz

Also, the snippet to convert a matplotlib-format element to a opencv-format element can be shrinked to this function:

```
def convert_matplotlib_to_opencv_img(matplotlib_format_img, clear=False, transitory_img_path='my_transitory_img.jpg'):

    if clear:
        plt.clf()

    plt.plot(matplotlib_format_img)

    try:
        plt.savefig(transitory_img_path)
    except: 
        raise OSError("could not save img to {}".format(transitory_img_path))

    cv2_imread_format_img = cv2.imread(transitory_img_path)

    import os
    try: 
        os.remove(transitory_img_path)
    except: 
        print("could not remove {}".format(transitory_img_path))

    return cv2_imread_format_img
```

Comment: this is merely using `plt.savefig()` as a workaround. this doesn't need Pillow (unless matplotlib _optionally_ requires that for the operation, which I doubt). there are ways to get that plotted image without saving it to a file too.

Comment: Question updated. Thanks again! :)